# Why does the same way of opening and writing a file gives me error the second time? ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, file, while-loop, io, infinite-loop

I am trying to write the title of a opened youtube video on "api obs.txt" and its URL on "link obs.txt". The title gets written but it says "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." when writing the URL.

```
while True:
    atual = driver.current_url
    with open('link obs.txt', 'r') as file:
        linksalvo = file.readline()

  #if current is different than the saved url
if atual != linksalvo: 
    #write the new title on the file for the api to read
    with open('api obs.txt', 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        html = urlopen(atual)
        html = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
        print(html.title.get_text())
        #write the URL of the current video to the file for comparison later
    with open('link obs.txt', 'w') as f:
        print(driver.current_url) #"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." Happens on this line

        
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

- Unrelated problem: the loop is a while true loop but if the page doesnt have a title it will give a error message and halt. I also dont know how to make the code ignore the error and keep looking until the current page has a title.

Comment: You set stdout to `f`. Then you closed `f`. (You set `f` to another file, but stdout is still set to the old (closed) file.) Then you tried to `print` something (to stdout). But stdout is now pointing to a closed file. Suggestion: don't reassign stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do `sys.stdout = f`, any operation on `f` will also be done on `sys.stdout`. Leaving that `with` block closes `f`, so it also closes `sys.stdout`.

Then when you later do `print(driver.current_url)`, it tries to write this to `sys.stdout`, but it's closed, so you get an error. You need to use `sys.stdout = f` again after opening the second file.

I recommend you don't redefine `sys.stdout` in the first place. You can use the `file` argument to `print()` to write to a specific file object.

```
if atual != linksalvo: 
    #write the new title on the file for the api to read
    with open('api obs.txt', 'w') as f:
        html = urlopen(atual)
        html = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
        print(html.title.get_text(), file=f)
        #write the URL of the current video to the file for comparison later
    with open('link obs.txt', 'w') as f:
        print(driver.current_url, file=f) #"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." Happens on this line
```